# How to remove undefined error in angular js?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-scope, angular-ui-router

How to remove undefined  error in angular js ?Actually i am trying to load data in using resolve and use that data in controller but on controller i am getting **undefined** why ?

```
resolve: {
    message: function (testservice) {
        return testservice.getdata();
    },
    message2: function (testservice) {
        return testservice.getTodo();
    },
    message3: function (testservice) {
        return testservice.getGithub();
    }
}
```

use the controller

```
.controller('b', function($scope, $stateParams, $state, $ionicHistory,message) {
    console.log("controller is loaded"+message)
})
```

// undefined in this console

```
console.log("controller is loaded"+message)
```

plinker
http://plnkr.co/edit/siqCUS3jUKVQz6pxmC50?p=preview

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would say, that you are almost there.

Just the service/factory must return something. I mean here:

```
...
message: function(testservice) {
      return testservice.getdata();
}
```

we expect something... and there was nothing

I added one line **`return data;`** and there is [that updated plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/k0krNLr683TtJ2XEoOPn?p=preview)

```
.factory('testservice', ['$http',
  function testservice($http) {
    // interface

    // implementation
    function getData() {

      return $http.get("http://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/photos")
        .then(function(data) {
          console.log(data)

          // HERE - this line was missing
          // return something here
          return data;

        }, function(error) {
          console.log(error)
        })
```

#### EXTEND: How to show some view ...loading... before resolve is done?

Based on some comments I extended [**the example here**](http://plnkr.co/edit/ZNClHVL8v8k9T3Xqmry2?p=preview). It is now showing this view:

loadingB.html

```
<div >
  <div ui-view="">
    <h2>...loading...</h2>
  </div>
</div>
```

which is a view of a brand new parent state **`'loadingB'`**:

```
.state('loadingB', {
  redirectTo: "b",
  templateUrl : "loadingB.html",
})
```

It injects the above view loadingB.html in position of original state 'b'. And it has one property **`redirectTo: "b"`**, which is managed by this small piece of code:

```
.run(['$rootScope', '$state', function($rootScope, $state) {
    $rootScope.$on('$stateChangeSuccess', function(evt, to, params) {
      if (to.redirectTo) {
        evt.preventDefault();
        $state.go(to.redirectTo, params)
      }
    });
}])
```

And our service now uses **`$timeout`** to get some delay:

```
.factory('testservice', ['$http', '$timeout',
  function testservice($http, $timeout) { 
    // interface

    // implementation
    function getData() { 

      return $http.get("http://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/photos")
        .then(function(data) {
          console.log("resolved http")
          return $timeout(function(){
            console.log("after two seconds delay")
            return data;
          }, 2500)
        ...
```

And finally, we have to redirect to `loadingB` here

```
$scope.moveto = function() {
    $state.go('loadingB'); 
}
```

And also make the 'b' child of 'laodingB'

```
.state("b", {
  parent: "loadingB", 
  templateUrl: "b.html",
  url: "/b",
  controller: 'b', 
  resolve: { 
    message: function(testservice) {
      return testservice.getdata();
    },
```

Check it all [here](http://plnkr.co/edit/ZNClHVL8v8k9T3Xqmry2?p=preview)

Comment: I need to show loader till all service data will not come

Comment: Well, the UI-Router `resolve: {}` setting is intended to work... the way, that state is not issued, till all the data are loaded (resolved).

Comment: can we show loader as given in this http://ionicframework.com/docs/api/service/$ionicLoading/

Comment: Let me check that, to be sure that I understand you

Comment: I think I need use $q.all().if all data come I need to hide loader ..or can I use other method

Comment: NO, no no. UI-Router (inside of ionic) has solution. The state is never started until ALL resolve statements are loaded.

Comment: so wat is solution ? how to show loader ,till all data get from service.

Comment: This is a bit different than your issue in the question, but - give me few minutes

Comment: I extended my answer, created new plunker with all that in play and tried to explain how it works. Hope now you have your answer... Good luck

Answer (score 1):

Radim Koehler has the correct answer, or even easier, just return the promise from the getData function in the service:

```
function getData() { 
      return $http.get("http://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/photos");
}
```

Comment: Exactly ;) That is the essence of the resolve - return something ;)

Answer (score 0):

If you want to resolve state before going into view, then you need to do few things. resolve you state like this

```
.state('app.b', {
  url: "/b",
  views: {
    'menuContent': {
      templateUrl: "b.html",
      controller: 'b',
      resolve: {
        apiData: "testservice",
        itemDetailsData: function($q, apiData) {
          var item = apiData.getdata();
          if (item) {
            return $q.when(item);
          } else {
            return $q.reject();
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
})
```

in you services you can have factory method like :

```
.factory('albumService', ['$http', '$q', '$ionicLoading', '$timeout', albumFn])
function albumFn($http, $q, $ionicLoading, $timeout) {
return {
getAlbums: function() {
  $ionicLoading.show({
    content: '<i class="icon ion-loading-d"></i>',
    animation: 'fade-in',
    showBackdrop: true,
    maxWidth: 200,
    showDelay: 5
  });

  var def = $q.defer();
  $http.get("data.json")
    .success(function(data) {
     $ionicLoading.hide();
      def.resolve(data);
    })
    .error(function() {
     $ionicLoading.hide();
      def.reject("Failed to get albums");
    });

  return def.promise;

    }
  }
 }
```

I have created similar plunker demo [here](http://plnkr.co/edit/iY0sCnM5dzvassz2k0KL?p=preview)