# ui-router: do not wait for all resolves to be resolved to display the views

Tags: angularjs, promise, angular-ui-router

I am using ui-router to load differents subviews on a given state. Some views require resources which take a long time to resolve so I'd like to display my other views as soon as they are ready.

Here is the way I am fetching my resources:

```
.config(['$stateProvider', '$routeProvider',  
    function ($stateProvider, $routeProvider) {
        $stateProvider
            .state('test', {
                abstract: true,
                url: '/test',
                views: {
                    'main': {
                         template:  '<h1>Hello!!!</h1>' +
                                    '<div ui-view="view1"></div>' +
                                    '<div ui-view="view2"></div>'
                    }
                }
            })
            .state('test.subs', {
                url: '',
                views: {
                    'view1@test': {
                        template: "Im View1: {{ item }}",
                        controller: 'View1Ctrl',
                        resolve: {
                            test1: function () { return 'yo' }
                        }
                    },
                    'view2@test': {
                        template: "Im View2: {{ item }}",
                        controller: 'View2Ctrl',
                        resolve: {
                            // This takes a lot of time to resolve
                            test2: function ($q, $timeout) { 
                                var deferred = $q.defer()
                                $timeout(function () { deferred.resolve('boom') }, 5000)
                                return deferred.promise
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            });
    }])
```

I created a JSFiddle to exemplify my issue:
http://jsfiddle.net/o76uq5oe/6/

Is there a way not to wait for all the promises to be resolved?

Comment: As far as I know, until now, all resolves must be resolved, to let state start. But ... there is a kindo of way how to get arround. There is a description and example http://stackoverflow.com/a/32799422/1679310

Comment: You can skip returning the promise, but you will not have "heavyResource" injected in your controller

Comment: I'd like to have the heavyResource injected in the controller but, I'd like my other views, which dont need this resource, to display as soon as resource1 has been fetched

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This happens because `resolve` promises should be resolved in order for the state transition to be completed, that's why `resolve` dependencies are there. It doesn't matter if they were defined for the state itself or for its particular view. From [the manual](http://angular-ui.github.io/ui-router/site/#/api/ui.router.state.$stateProvider#methods_state):

> If all the promises are resolved successfully, the $stateChangeSuccess
>   event is fired and the values of the resolved promises are injected
>   into any controllers that reference them. If any of the promises are
>   rejected the $stateChangeError event is fired.

It can be done if the views belong to separate states. The workaround is possible with [sticky states](http://christopherthielen.github.io/ui-router-extras/#/sticky) from ui-router-extras, [like that](http://jsfiddle.net/4hL55a3n/):

```
        ...
        .state('test.subs', {
            views: {
                'view1@test': {
                    template: "Im View1: {{ item }}",
                    controller: 'View1Ctrl',
                    resolve: {
                        test1: function () { return 'yo' }
                    }
                },
            },
            sticky: true,
            onEnter: function ($state) {
              $state.transition.then(function () {
                $state.go('test.subs.view2')
              });
            }            
        })
        .state('test.subs.view2', {
            views: {
                'view2@test': {
                    template: "Im View2: {{ item }}",
                    controller: 'View2Ctrl',
                    resolve: {
                        test2: function ($q, $timeout) { 
                            var deferred = $q.defer()
                            $timeout(function () { deferred.resolve('boom') }, 1000)
                            return deferred.promise
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        });
```

Otherwise the dependency should be resolved in view controller, like it would be done without router and `resolve`.

Comment: someViews2 has to wait for heavyResource, so I want it injected in the controller BUT someViews1 doesnt need it at all so it should be rendered as soon as resource1 is fetched

Comment: Then you just put heavyResource as 'resolve' dependency for one view and omit it for another, right?

Comment: not sure, take a look at this jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/o76uq5oe/1/
You see that the timeout delay the rendering of the whole page

Comment: @Spearfisher Ok, I see now what you're trying to achieve. See the updated answer. Notice that fiddle js dependencies were updated to actual versions.